# The best (or most conventionally acceptable) way to describe under-representation of a group in a sub-population

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Suppose that 50% of the population at large are women, but in a certain field, only 20% of the professionals are women.  Suppose further that I want to write a bullet point that reads:

```
"Women are under-represented by X in this field"
```

What is the best/most conventional way to choose X?

I am aware that there are many plausible answers, for example:

- 30% since 50-20 = 30
- 60% since 20/50 = 0.4
- 75% since there are 4 men for each woman and (1/4)/(1/1) = 0.25

I am also aware that it might just be better to simply say "women are 50% of the general population and just 20% in this field", avoiding ambiguity.

But assuming that I want a statistic to capture the amount of under-representation, is there a convention here, or an persuasive argument for picking one of those numbers (or one not on that list)?

Answer (score 0):

It's best to just say "Only 20% of workers in this field are women." Readers are likely to already know that about 51% of living people are women. It's only necessary to quote a figure for the larger population if you have a more specific larger population in mind, such as the population of American college students.